# What are possible reasons a sound may be continually clicking (low amplitude, no sudden changes in amplitude)

Tags: noise, sound

I am making a digital sound mixer and get [this wav file (200kb, Wetransfer)](https://we.tl/t-3TMW3Nsw6p)

I looked through the waveform using Audacity. It uses 20% of its maximum amplitude and I see no sudden changes in the waveform.

Yet it repeatedly clicks.

It is composed (not maxed) sine waves, first 1, later 4. But the waveform looks like I avoided constructive interference (by reducing volume).

Interestingly when combined with other sounds (music, ambience), the clicking is almost removed.

Comment: Can you post the code how this is generated? Could be all sorts of things: dropped samples, phase or amplitude discontinuity in one of all of the oscillators. This can be reverse engineered but it's a rather tedious process. I'm guessing it's related to the amplitude management, which looks too smooth to me. How exactly do you "reduce volume" ?

Comment: @Hilmar thank you. Can not be dropped samples, see the waveform. Oscillators: don't worry about that, this mixer is not even intended for that but arbitrary tracks. Too smooth: I did not know that that is a thing. Reduced volume by multiplying a constant (there are no artifacts, as you can see in the waveform)

Comment: Can you post your code? Guessing blindly is not going to work here.

Comment: @Hilmar sorry, can not do that and it is unlikely that it would show you something that the waveform does not

Comment: Well, there is obviously something wrong  with the code otherwise it wouldn't be clicking

Comment: The clicking is a feature of the waveform! It would be just the same if I found the file somewhere. Please just let someone else give me a tip what could cause clicks (besides clipping and jumping which are not in this waveform)

Comment: @BerndElkemann Clipping does not happen. Jumping does, and it is obvious it jumps.

Comment: @BerndElkemann Do you want us to simply analyze the nature of the clicking, i.e. how can it sound like a click without looking like a click?  Without any attention to what might cause it?

Comment: @Edward I have accepted an answer, don't worry about this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is clearly something wrong but it's not easy to tell what it is. In order to analyze I ran the signal through a bandstop filter which should ideally eliminate the entire signal.

It can be clearly seen that there strong spikes in the band-stopped signal which  are a strong indicator of out of band energy, i.e. they happen where the clicks are. So the location of the clicks can easily be identified this way but there isn't anything obviously wrong with the waveform, so further analysis is required.

Without more details on how exactly the signal is generated, this is difficult to do. You would probably have to manually build the individual sine waves and subtract them out, which is rather tedious to do.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for analyzing the waveform! I will try to work with this to find the problem

Comment: By zooming in on the waveform, it clearly has periodic discontinuities that   have an unusually large jump in the samples, as if there was a sample missing.

Comment: Such a situation could occur, for example, if you generated a sine wave with a certain number of samples that isn't a multiple of the period, then extended it to a longer duration by repeating this fragment instead of generating more of the wave

Answer (score 14):

There are discontinuities in the waveform.

Please open the file in a program that allows you to zoom in on the waveform.

There is a visible click at 0.9404 seconds, after sample number 20735.

[image: Screenshot from Audacity, showing a sudden change in amplitude at timestamp 0.9404 s.]

It looks like a sample has been skipped.

On the other hand, when somewhere else a sample was skipped, it looks like exactly 128 samples before there is a problem where a sample has been doubled.

So whatever algorithm is producing the waveforms, it has a bug generating continuous waveforms, and instead sometimes a sample is doubled or skipped.

Comment: +1 but I saw that someone else -1'ed this earlier. I will check this too, thank you

Answer (score -1):

Plotting the WAV file shared, it looks like the signal is clipped.

Yes, it only goes to 20% of the full-scale value, but the fact that it's pretty much ALL limited to 0.2 (20%), suggests that the value is clipped.

[image: Plot of shared WAV file.]

Such clipping will cause clicks.

The reason the clicks disappear when adding other signals is probably because those other signals have the effect of aurally smoothing them out. That doesn't mean they are gone, just that they're not as easily heard.

Comment: Thank you, but zoom in! Zoom in by a lot until you can see the waveform. The wave is perfect, not clipped.

Comment: The waveform is not clipped and it is not perfect either.

Comment: @BerndElkemann If it were "perfect" there would be no clicks.  Can you share how you created the signal?

Comment: Or it's just a computer-generated waveform that always has the same amplitude by design

Comment: @user253751 Possibly! But we don't have enough information from the OP to be sure.

Comment: -1, A signal which is clipped will have regular peaks at some value, but regular peaks at some value don't necessarily indicate that the signal is clipped, it could be e.g. computer generated sine waves.  Further inspection would suggest that the signal is NOT clipped.

Comment: @Edward Until I see how the signal was generated, I'm not convinced either way.

Answer (score -1):

A suggestion of something to check... do all your sine waves have the same phase?

Adding sine waves with same phase will result in constructive spikes in signals.

Comment: This is not the issue (it's clear from simply listening to the file that something else is wrong)